# What does notifier.performChange actually do?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-harmony, object.observe

I am trying to understand `Object.getNotifier(object).performChange`. Conceptually I understand that it is designed for defining "macro" or higher level changes. From the [example everyone seems to refer to](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es7/observe/):

```
increment: function(amount) {
  var notifier = Object.getNotifier(this);

  notifier.performChange(Thingy.INCREMENT, function() {
    this.a += amount;
    this.b += amount;
  }, this);

  notifier.notify({
    object: this,
    type: Thingy.INCREMENT,
    incremented: amount
  });
}
```

What I do not understand is, how is this different from simply executing the anonymous function passed to `notifier.performChange` directly, instead of as a callback? In other words, how does it differ from the below:

```
increment: function(amount) {
  var notifier = Object.getNotifier(this);

  this.a += amount;
  this.b += amount;

  notifier.notify({
    object: this,
    type: Thingy.INCREMENT,
    incremented: amount
  });
}
```

I have seen that in the latest spec, `notifier.performChange` may return an object, which is then issued as a notification, as in:

```
notifier.performChange(Thing.INCREMENT, function() {
    this.a += amount;
    this.b += amount;

    // a notification is issues with this return value,
    // including the type passed to notifier.performChange,
    // and the object underlying notifier. 
    return {incremented: amount};  
});
```

That eliminates the need for the following `notifier.notify` in the original code, but still, is this something other than sugar, or is there a functional difference between this and just making the changes and issuing the notification yourself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After an hour of doing a lot of testing I finally figured it out. I had the same question (what is `performChange` for?), and also the same idea to just take that off and call

```
this.a += amount;
this.b += amount;
```

However: the point of `notifier.performChange` is so that the observer does not observe each change.

I was testing it like this:

```
var obj = {
  x: 5,
  y: 10
};

function noti() {
  console.log('noti start');
  var notifier = Object.getNotifier(obj);

  notifier.performChange('ok', function() {
    obj.x++;
    obj.y++;
  });

  notifier.notify({
    type: 'ok',
    oldValue: 5
  });
  console.log('noti end');
};

function noti2() {
  console.log('noti2 start');
  var notifier = Object.getNotifier(obj);

  obj.x++;
  obj.y++;

  notifier.notify({
    type: 'ok',
    oldValue: 5
  });
  console.log('noti2 end');
};

function observer(changes) {
  for (var change of changes) {
    console.log('observer: change =', change, ' newValue=', change.object[change.name]);
  }
};

Object.observe(obj, observer, ['ok', 'update']);

console.log('calling noti2()');
noti2(); //will log the changes of update twice becuase of the x and y property of obj

// add delay manually because observer calls are asynchronous and
// we want to clearly separate the notification function calls in our logs
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('calling noti()');

  noti(); //will only log the ok type. that's what they mean by big change
          //so everything you do inside the performChange won't be observed
}, 100);
```

It should return the following console output:

```
calling noti2()
noti2 start
noti2 end
observer: change = Object {type: "update", object: Object, name: "x", oldValue: 5}  newValue= 6
observer: change = Object {type: "update", object: Object, name: "y", oldValue: 10}  newValue= 11
observer: change = Object {object: Object, type: "ok", oldValue: 5}  newValue= undefined

calling noti()
noti start
noti end
observer: change = Object {object: Object, type: "ok", oldValue: 5}  newValue= undefined
```

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to provide a definitive answer to this question I was also asking myself, so I had a look at the [Object.observe spec](https://github.com/arv/ecmascript-object-observe).

Here's what you need to know about what `Object.getNotifier(obj).performChange(changeType, changeFn)` does:

- It runs `changeFn`
- While `changeFn` is running, it purposely doesn't notify any observer of the changes that may happen to properties of `obj`
- You can make `changeFn` return an object: `obj`'s observers will be notified with that object's own properties

To see for yourself, [`%NotifierPrototype%.performChange(changeType, changeFn)`](http://arv.github.io/ecmascript-object-observe/#notifierprototype_.performchange) is what you're looking for in the spec.

Applied to your examples, this means these two lead to exactly the same result, while doing things a little differently:

Example 1:

```
increment: function(amount) {
    var notifier = Object.getNotifier(this);

    notifier.performChange(Thingy.INCREMENT, function() {
        this.a += amount;
        this.b += amount;
    });

    notifier.notify({
        object: this,
        type: Thingy.INCREMENT,
        incremented: amount
    });
}
```

In this first example:

- As per `performChange()`'s behavior, changes to the object's properties inside the callback function will be kept silent
- Since the callback function returns `undefined`, `performChange()` won't notify any observer of anything else
- However, calling `notify()` at the end explicitly notifies the appropriate observers with the change record passed

Example 2:

```
increment: function(amount) {
    var notifier = Object.getNotifier(this);

    notifier.performChange(Thingy.INCREMENT, function() {
        this.a += amount;
        this.b += amount;

        return { incremented: amount };  
    });
}
```

In this second example:

- As per `performChange()`'s behavior, changes to the object's properties inside the callback function will be kept silent
- Since the callback function returns an object, `performChange()` will notify the appropriate observers with an object that looks the same as the one resulting from explicitly calling `notify()` in example 1: `{ object: Object, type: Thingy.INCREMENT, increment: amount }`

These two examples should cover most cases where you'd want to use `performChange()`, and how you can use it. I'm going to keep diving though, for this beast's behavior is quite interesting.

---

### Asynchronicity

Observers are executed asynchronously. That means that everything that happens inside the `increment()` function in the examples above is actually reported to the observer *once `increment()` has finished executing* – and only then.

In other words, all of these:

- Making a change to the observed object's properties outside of `performChange()`
- Returning an object in `performChange()`'s callback
- Calling `notify()`

Will only notify the appropriate observer once `increment()` has finished running.

### Synchronous change delivery

If you need to be aware of the pending changes during `increment()`'s execution (pending changes = all changes that will be reported to observers at the end of `increment()`, but haven't yet), there's a solution: `Object.deliverChangeRecords(callback)`.

Be aware though that `callback` needs to be a reference to a function you've already registered as an observation callback for that object before.

In other words, this won't work:

```js
(function() {
    var obj = { prop: "a" };

    Object.observe(obj, function(changes) {
        console.log(changes);
    });
    
    obj.prop = "b";

    Object.deliverChangeRecords(function(changes) {
        console.log(changes);
    });

    console.log("End of execution");
})(); // Meh, we're notified of changes here, which isn't what we wanted
```

While this will:

```js
(function() {
    var obj = { prop: "a" },

        callback = function(changes) {
            console.log(changes);
        };
    
    Object.observe(obj, callback)

    obj.prop = "b";

    Object.deliverChangeRecords(callback); // Notified of changes here, synchronously: yay!

    console.log("End of execution");
})();
```

The reason for this is that internally, calling `Object.observe(obj, callback)` for an object `obj` will add the passed `callback` function to `obj`'s list of observation callbacks (known as `[[ChangeObservers]]` in the spec). Each of these callbacks will only be executed for specific types of changes (the third `Object.observe()` argument), or *all default ones* if no argument is passed. *(This is an important detail, since that means that if you want to use a custom `type` of change, you'll need to explicitly pass it to `Object.observe()`'s third argument, otherwise you won't be notified of any changes of that type.)*

Additionally, every pending change will be added to every matching observation callback's queue internally. That means every observation callback has its own set of pending changes.

And that's exactly what `Object.deliverChangeRecords(callback)` is for: it takes all pending changes for `callback` and executes that callback by passing it all these changes.

That explains why `deliverChangeRecords()` only requires one argument, that of the callback. As illustrated by the example below, passing a callback to `deliverChangeRecords()` will execute that callback with *all* its pending changes, including changes from multiple objects. This is in accordance with the general behavior of callbacks, might they be called asynchronously or through `deliverChangeRecords()`.

```js
(function() {
    var obj1 = { prop1: "a" },
        obj2 = { prop2: "a" },

        commonCallback = function(changes) {
            console.log(changes);
        };
    
    Object.observe(obj1, commonCallback);
    Object.observe(obj2, commonCallback);

    obj1.prop1 = "b";
    obj2.prop2 = "b";

    Object.deliverChangeRecords(commonCallback); // Notified of the changes to both obj1.prop1 and obj2.prop2
})();
```

Also, *great* [usage examples](http://arv.github.io/ecmascript-object-observe/#examples) are available in the spec.

Comment: Great and clear answer on a rather obscure subject. It also clarify the role of the type to `performChange`.

Comment: Good answer, but the 2nd link isn't working unfortunately.

Comment: @FabianLauer Thanks for the heads-up! I've updated the links :)